# Why is my Django rest framework api returning an empty list?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Hello I am working on an Django Rest Framework api and one of the views is returning an empty list.

here's my view:

```py
@api_view(['GET'])
def post_search(request):
    form = SearchForm()
    query = None
    results = []
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if 'query' in request.GET:
            form = SearchForm(request.GET)
            if form.is_valid():
                query = form.cleaned_data['query']
                results = Paper.objects.annotate(
                    search=SearchVector('abstract', 'title'),).filter(search=query)
        serializer = PaperSerializer(results, many=True)

        return Response(serializer.data)
```

here is the form:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    query = forms.CharField()
```

and here are my urls:

```
path('search/', views.post_search, name='post_search'),
```

So on the shell I ran:

```
Paper.objects.annotate(search=SearchVector('abstract', 'title'),).filter(search='Type')
```

and I got the results I wanted but when do this:

```
import requests
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/search/?search=Type'
re = requests.get(url)
re.json # -> []
# or
import json
json.loads(re) # ->raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, # bytes or bytearray, '
#TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not Response
```

Any help will be appreciated; thanks

Comment: is query present in request.GET?

Comment: @sahasrara62 how do I check this? sorry for my ignorance but im new to web dev.

Comment: You can add `import pdb; pdb,set_trace()`, after `if request.method == 'GET':` and restart application and then hit the end point, in terminal run `'query' in request.GET`, if it is False then is root cause of your error

Comment: `'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/search/?search=Type'` That url does not contain a `query` arg, so `if 'query' in request.GET` will be false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the form.

The form as I had was:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    query = forms.CharField()
```

the field here `query` didn't match with `search` in the url. So all I did was change the form to this:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    search = forms.CharField()
```

lessons: the field of the form needs to match with the keywords in the url. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your parameter is `search` not <s>`query`</s>, so you check with `if 'search' in request.GET`. But you make things overcomplicated. You can work with:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    search = forms.CharField()


@api_view(['GET'])
def post_search(request):
    form = SearchForm(request.GET)
    if form.is_valid():
        results = Paper.objects.annotate(
            search=SearchVector('abstract', 'title')
        ).filter(search=form.cleaned_data['search'])
        serializer = PaperSerializer(results, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    return Response({'error': 'invalid search'}, status=400)
```

Comment: I get the error: ```Bad Request: /api/search/
[07/Jan/2023 23:43:08] "GET /api/search/?search=Type HTTP/1.1" 400 26```

Comment: @chez93: looks like it never "fires" the view, so something is wrong with your `urls.py` probably. Did you define a view with the same name? Did you forget to include the `urlpatterns` somewhere in the "top level" `urls.py`?

Comment: here is my top level url: ```path('api/', include('restapi.urls')),```

Comment: Try to hit the endpoint without the slash between the url and the parameter. Like this: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/search?search=Type`

Comment: @dsenese I tried bout urls - with slash and without it -- and when I do `re.json()` I get `{'error' : 'invalid search'}`